# angular + SignalR version is not defined on --prod build

Tags: angular, signalr.client

I have an angular app where we print some info to the console for some dependency versions. I added signalr client recently and am doing:

```
import { VERSION as SignalRVersion } from "@aspnet/signalr";
```

ng version

```
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@angular/cdk                      7.2.1
@angular/cli                      7.1.4
@angular/pwa                      0.11.4
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.2
webpack                           4.23.1
```

This worked fine but I recently added service worker to the app and to test I need to do 
`ng build --prod` 
then 
`http-server -c-1 /dist/app-name`.

The service worker and app load fine but the SignalRVersion is not defined. ng serve is fine.
I looked in the node_modules folder for @aspnet/signalr and there is `export var VERSION = "1.0.4";` so it should be fine but it chokes on a prod build.